# Cant start http_redirect service on Ubuntu 18

Tags: http, systemd, ubuntu-18.04

Im having a lot of difficulty starting the service on Ubuntu 18.

After running service http_redirect status - i get `/etc/systemd/system/http_redirect.service:6: Executable path is not absolute: http_redirect`.

Below is my .service file

```
[Unit] 
Description=http_redirect

[Service]  
Environment= 
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/http_redirect
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID 
KillSignal=TERM User=root
WorkingDirectory=/usr/local/bin 
Restart=on-failure 

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The http_redirect file does exist and is executable. Is there anything wrong here?

Comment: Did you issue `systemctl daemon-reload` after editing the file? Also, you may be missing a line break, unless that was a copy/paste error.

Comment: That worked!! Thanks, Daniel :)

Answer (score 0):

In your `.service` file, you definitely have an absolute path for `ExecStart`. But if you only edited the file after you received the error message, Systemd has already cached the unit.

After making changes to Systemd units, always issue the `systemctl daemon-reload` command. Sometimes, `systemctl` will also remind you automatically.

(The line with `KillSignal=TERM` also has `User=root` in it, may or may not be a copy-paste mistake.)